# Output Error in RainFall Program in java

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote a program about calculating the average of raining in a year and give me the highest and the lowest amount but I am getting an error and I couldn't fix it.

This is my main code : `

```
public class Rainfall {

//field 
private double [] rain;

public void Rainfall (double [] array) {

    rain = new double [array.length] ; 

    for (int i=0; i < array.length ; i++) 

        rain [i] = array [i];   
}

//Methods
public double getTotal() {

    double total = 0;

    for ( double r : rain)

total +=r;
    return total;

}

public double getAverage () {

    double a = getTotal () / rain.length;

    return a;
}

public double getHighest () { 

    double highest = rain [0];

    for (int i=0 ; i < rain.length; i++) { 

        if (rain [i] > highest) ;
        highest = rain [i];
}
    return highest;         
}

public double getLowest () {

    double lowest = rain [0];

    for ( int i=0; i <rain.length; i++) { 

        if (rain [i] < lowest) ;

        lowest = rain [i];
    }
    return lowest;
}

}
```

`
and this is the demo :

```
`
  import java.util.Scanner;
  import java.text.DecimalFormat;


  public class RainFallDemo { 

    public static void main (String [] args ) throws NullPointerException
 { 


        final int year1 = 12;

        double [] rains = new double [year1];

        getData (rains) ;

        Rainfall rainfallData = new Rainfall ();

        DecimalFormat values = new DecimalFormat ("#0.00") ;

        System.out.println("The total rain is" + values.format(rainfallData.getTotal()));
        System.out.println("The average is " + values.format (rainfallData.getAverage()));
        System.out.println("The highest rain is " + values.format (rainfallData.getHighest()));
        System.out.println("The lowest is " + values.format (rainfallData.getLowest()));




    }

    public static void getData (double [] array) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in) ;

        for ( int i=0 ; i < array.length; i++) 
        {

            System.out.println ("what was the amont of rain for month  " + (i + 1) + "?");

            array [i] = keyboard.nextDouble ();

            while (array[i] < 0 )
            {
                System.out.print ( " Invalid input. You entered a negative number. Enter a" + 
            "value that is greater than zero");
            array [i] = keyboard.nextDouble ();

            }
    }
}
}`
```

I was getting the wrong lowest and wrong highest and The program has to show which month had the lowest and highest in the output but but I can't figure out the code!!

Comment: `public void Rainfall (double [] array)` is **not** a constructor. Constructors should not have *any* return type and this includes `void`.

Comment: Thank You man, I fixed the error but could you help me with the other part? @PM77-1  //// I am getting this output : The total rain is561.00
The average is 46.75
The highest rain is 99.00
The lowest is 11.00    I am wondering what should I write that the program in the output could say which month had the highest and lowest amount of raining

Answer (score 4):

Remove the semicolon at the end of your if lines. That is causing the if to execute an empty statement when it is true. Then the next line is always executed no matter what.

Comment: Thank You man, I fixed the error but could you help me with the other part? //// I am getting this output : The total rain is561.00
The average is 46.75
The highest rain is 99.00
The lowest is 11.00    I am wondering what should I write that the program in the output could say which month had the highest and lowest amount of raining

Comment: You could do a couple of things: add  public int getHighestMonth() that mimicks the logic of getHighest() but returns i instead of rain[i], or my preferred way would be to add class members int highMonth, lowMonth; and set them inside of getHighest and getLowest. In that case I would also add members long highest, lowest; and change getHighest() to void calculateHighest();

Comment: Ben I am really appreciate your help but still I am a little confuse. could you write the getHighestMonth() code for me?